# I have error an mysql connection with tomcat server

Tags: java, sql

My code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class sqlConnection {
    
    private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hosapi";
    private static String uname = "root";
    private static String pword = "1016";
    
    
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        
        Connection con = null;
    
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, pword);
            System.out.println("connection created");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

}
```

error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 322 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 297 milliseconds ago.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:981)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:164)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:4801)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1643)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1215)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2255)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
    at com.project.Hospital.sqlConnection.main(sqlConnection.java:19)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:240)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:448)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:149)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Possibly related: [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2983248)

Comment: Maybe try ```private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hosapi?useSSL=false";```

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.